# How can I load my 2nd dynamic drop down list on pageload?

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have a dynamic drop down menu which consits of two drop down lists.

When the page loads, the 2nd drop down list is empty, however I would like to have both lists displayed by default. Please see http://jazzkatt.net/dynamic/ to illustrate my problem.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
  $(function() {

    $("#json-one").change(function() {
    var $dropdown = $(this);
      $.getJSON("jsondata/data.json", function(data) {
        var key = $dropdown.val();
        var vals = [];

        switch(key) {
          case 'norway':
          vals = data.norway.split(",");
        break;
          case 'usa':
          vals = data.usa.split(",");
        break;
          case 'denmark':
          vals = data.denmark.split(",");
        }

        var $jsontwo = $("#json-two");
        $jsontwo.empty();
        $.each(vals, function(index, value) {
        $jsontwo.append("<option>" + value + "</option>");
        });

      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

And here is the HMTL code I use to display the drop down lists:

```
    <select id="json-one">
        <option selected value="norway">Norway</option>
        <option value="usa">USA</option>
        <option value="denmark">Denmark</option>
    </select>

    <br />

    <select id="json-two">

    </select>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to trigger the first dropdown when the document gets ready.
So please make these changes

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // Change 1

    $("#json-one").change(function() {
    var $dropdown = $(this);
      $.getJSON("jsondata/data.json", function(data) {
        var key = $dropdown.val();
        var vals = [];

        switch(key) {
          case 'norway':
          vals = data.norway.split(",");
        break;
          case 'usa':
          vals = data.usa.split(",");
        break;
          case 'denmark':
          vals = data.denmark.split(",");
        }

        var $jsontwo = $("#json-two");
        $jsontwo.empty();
        $.each(vals, function(index, value) {
            $jsontwo.append("<option>" + value + "</option>");
        });

      });
    });

    $("#json-one").trigger('change'); // Change 2
  });
```

Comment: Excellent, that worked like a charm :-) Thanks a million.

Comment: Its my pleasure :-)

Comment: @Sanoop Thanks, I didn't realize. I have now accepted the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could just trigger `change` event, e.g:

```
$(function() {

    $("#json-one").change(function() {
    var $dropdown = $(this);
      $.getJSON("jsondata/data.json", function(data) {
        var key = $dropdown.val();
        var vals = [];

        switch(key) {
          case 'norway':
          vals = data.norway.split(",");
        break;
          case 'usa':
          vals = data.usa.split(",");
        break;
          case 'denmark':
          vals = data.denmark.split(",");
        }

        var $jsontwo = $("#json-two");
        $jsontwo.empty();
        $.each(vals, function(index, value) {
        $jsontwo.append("<option>" + value + "</option>");
        });

      });
    }).change(); //<< trigger change event
  });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the logic to check the country selected on change event it is fired only when a value is selected from dropdown. One quick solution i might suggest would be to put the same logic on document.ready event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //load the city based on country selected
});
```

Hope this might give you a starting point

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The second list is only generated once there is a change in the first list ("#json-one").

If you want to generate the second list on page load you need to do this in your init function.

> ```
>   $(function() {
>   $.getJSON("jsondata/data.json", function(data) {
>     var key = $("#json-one").val()
>     var vals = [];
>
>    switch(key) {
>       case 'norway':
>       vals = data.norway.split(",");
>     break;
>       case 'usa':
>       vals = data.usa.split(",");
>     break;
>       case 'denmark':
>       vals = data.denmark.split(",");
>     }
>
>    var $jsontwo = $("#json-two");
>     $jsontwo.empty();
>     $.each(vals, function(index, value) {
>     $jsontwo.append("<option>" + value + "</option>");
>     });
>
>  });
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It's too easy. Just replace your code with below code and it will work.

```js
< script >

  $(document).ready(function() {

    function getJsonOneDropdownSelectedValue() {

      return $("#json-one").val();
    }

    function populateJosnTwoDropdown() {
      $.getJSON("jsondata/data.json", function(data) {
        var key = getJsonOneDropdownSelectedValue();
        var vals = [];

        switch (key) {
          case 'norway':
            vals = data.norway.split(",");
            break;
          case 'usa':
            vals = data.usa.split(",");
            break;
          case 'denmark':
            vals = data.denmark.split(",");
        }

        var $jsontwo = $("#json-two");
        $jsontwo.empty();
        $.each(vals, function(index, value) {
          $jsontwo.append("<option>" + value + "</option>");
        });

      });
    }

    // populate json two dropdown on the basic of json one
    populateJosnTwoDropdown();

    // register change event of json one dropdown
    $("#json-one").change(populateJosnTwoDropdown);

  });


< /script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="json-one">
  <option selected value="norway">Norway</option>
  <option value="usa">USA</option>
  <option value="denmark">Denmark</option>
</select>

<br />

<select id="json-two">

</select>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, much appreciated!